# withX() does not work in Laravel 4.2

Tags: php, laravel

The problem is that **withErrors()** is working perfectly in this code, but **withMessage()** isn't.

I also tried with('message', 'Test message!'). In views file, I can retrieve withErrors using $errors variable, but if I want to retrieve withMessage, I have to use Session::get('message'). Why is $message not working?

*Controller:*

```
public function registration() {
    $rules = array(...);
    $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);

    if($validator->fails()) {
        return Redirect::route('registration')->withErrors($validator);
    }
    else {
        //Some code here...

        return Redirect::route('registration')->withMessage('Test message!');
    }
}
```

*Template:*

```
@extends('default.base')

@section('main')
    @if(!empty($errors->all()))
        <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
            <ul>
                @foreach($errors->all() as $error)
                    <li>{{ $error }}
                @endforeach
            </ul>
        </div>
    @endif


    @if(isset($message))
    {{ $message }}
    @endif
@stop
```

Comment: Do you mean `return Redirect::route('registration')->with('message', 'Test message!');`? or perhaps `Session::flash('message', 'Test message!');`?

Comment: Yes, I have tried return Redirect::route('registration')->withMessage('Test message!'); and return Redirect::route('registration')->with('message', 'Test message!');

Comment: Show your template (or at least the relevant parts of it where you're accessing `$message`

Comment: I added my template file, @MarkBaker

Comment: `Redirect::route('registration')->with('message', 'Test message!');` should work, creating a variable called `$message` for access in blade... note that it is case sensitive

Comment: No, it's not working either. It does work with Session::get('message')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because `errors` is a special case. When creating a view, Laravel check's if there is a session variable with the name `errors`. If so it will then pass the contents as `$errors` to the view.

`Illuminate\View\ViewServiceProvider@registerSessionBinder`

```
if ($me->sessionHasErrors($app))
{
    $errors = $app['session.store']->get('errors');

    $app['view']->share('errors', $errors);
}
```

This means you either use `Session::has('message')` and `Session::get('message')` in your view or you add a [View Composer](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/responses#view-composers) that does basically the same that Laravel does with `errors`:

```
View::composer('*', function($view){
    if(Session::has('message')){
        $view->with('message', Session::get('message'));
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for a great answer. As I understand, I should use View Composer only if I use this variable often across the views, right? How about ->with(), does it create session variable like ->withX()?

Comment: @Andrius Yes, you have to use Sessions in ->with() case too.

Comment: `withX()` is just a shortcut for `with('x', ...)` so they do the exact same thing... And yes thats the purpose for view composers.